# WebCrawler Beautifulsoup Duplicate Output Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello i am trying to learn python and working with web scraping, as i run the web scrape it print several times the same line in the output(because the web site has same products in several different pages)  so my question is there a way that i can only print the product once even if its in several pages?
[Output picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWH2E.png)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://www.lamazuna.com/en/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

all_product_item_lists = soup.find_all(class_="col-sm-12 mega-col")

for product_link in all_product_item_lists:
    for link in product_link.find_all("a", href=True):
        find_product_url = link.get('href')

        next_page = requests.get(find_product_url)
        next_soup = BeautifulSoup(next_page.content, "html.parser")

        product_name_none = next_soup.find(class_="h3 product-title")
        product_price_none = next_soup.find(class_="price")



        if product_name_none is not None:
            product_name_several_times = product_name_none.get_text().replace("\n","")


        if product_price_none is not None:
           product_price = product_price_none.get_text().replace("\n","")

        print(product_name_several_times)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a title list then add title in it like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

titles = []

page = requests.get("https://www.lamazuna.com/en/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

all_product_item_lists = soup.find_all(class_="col-sm-12 mega-col")

for product_link in all_product_item_lists:
    for link in product_link.find_all("a", href=True):
        find_product_url = link.get('href')

        next_page = requests.get(find_product_url)
        next_soup = BeautifulSoup(next_page.content, "html.parser")

        product_name_none = next_soup.find(class_="h3 product-title")
     
        product_price_none = next_soup.find(class_="price")



        if product_name_none is not None:
            product_name_several_times = product_name_none.get_text().replace("\n","")
            if product_name_several_times not in titles:
                titles.append(product_name_several_times)

                print(f'"{product_name_several_times}" is added in list')   


        if product_price_none is not None:
           product_price = product_price_none.get_text().replace("\n","")

print(titles)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Samsul Islam, Been stuck some few days with no luck until now :)

Comment: It's happened. Thanks